# ember set component data from application controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to Ember and trying to figure out how the data routing works. I have a 'page-notices' component and template thats included in my application.hbs file. It handles showing error or other notifications to users. I cannot figure out how to set the data inside the component from the application controller.

When a user triggers a logout action in application controller, I send it to the server via ajax json request and then need to update the page-notices component if there was an error returned. What does the page-notices controller need to look like to get this done? Am I asking the wrong question and shouldn't be using the controller for this?

//app/templates/application.hbs

```
{{app-header}}
<div id="pagecontent">
    {{page-notices}}
    <div id="wrapper">
        {{outlet}}
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
</div>
{{app-footer}}
```

//app/controllers/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ENV from '/config/environment';

var $ = Ember.$;

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
pagenotices: Ember.inject.controller("page-notices")
actions: {
    logout: function() {
      var self = this;
      $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          method: 'GET',
          url: ENV.APP.apiHost,
          data: {p: 'logout'},
          success: function( response ){
            if( response.success || (response.loggedin == false) ){
              self.get('session').invalidate();
              self.transitionToLoginRoute();
            } else {
              self.get('pagenotices').set('pageerrors', response.error);
              self.get('pagenotices').set('pageerrorsview', '');
            }
          }
        });
    },
},
transitionToLoginRoute: function() {
  this.transitionToRoute('login');
},
});
```

//app/templates/components/page-notices.js

```
<div id="pagenotices" class="{{pagenoticeview}}">
    <div id="pageerrors" class="error centered {{pageerrorsview}}">{{pageerrors}}</div>
    <div id="pagemessages" class="notice centered {{pagemessagesview}}">{{pagemessages}}</div>
</div>
```

//app/components/page-notices.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ENV from '/config/environment';

const { inject: { service }, Component } = Ember;

export default Component.extend({
pagenoticeview: 'hide',
pageerrors: '',
pageerrorsview: 'hide',
pagemessages: '',
pagemessagesview: 'hide',
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not quite understand why you injected `page-notices` controller to `application` controller; because you have already put `page-notices` component directly to `application.hbs`. I might be wrong but I got the sense that you are confusing a `controller` and a `component`.

Anyway,the following should work.

1. Remove `pagenotices: Ember.inject.controller("page-notices")` this; since we have no work with `pagenotices` controller as I explained above.
2. Change the `else` part in ajax handler of `logout` action within `application.js` as follows:

   ```
     self.set('pageerrors', response.error);
     self.set('pageerrorsview', '');
   ```

   So that the corresponding attributes are directly saved to `application` controller itself.
3. Pass the corresponding attributes to `page-notices` component from within `application.hbs` with
   `{{page-notices pageerrors=pageerrors pageerrorsview=pageerrorsview}}`
4. Declare the initial values of `pageerrors` and `pageerorsview` within `application.js` and remove them from `page-notices` component if you want. I mean declarations of `pageerrors: '', pageerrorsview: 'hide'`

This should work if I got what you are asking right, best regards.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!